# After disassociating accounts, I am still the owner of my migrated answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, linked-accounts, association

I answered some questions on SO, they were migrated when meta was launched, I later created an account on meta and associated it with my SO account.  I (as in my meta identity) then became the owner of those answers, as normal.

However when I disassociated the accounts, my ownership of those answers stuck, and they are still associated with my meta account, even though I haven't touched those posts since they were moved to meta.

I would expect that my revisions to migrated questions and answers would show up under my username from the original site, grayed out, similar to what happens when the original poster has deleted their account.

Comment: I bet this is `status-bydesign`. At least that's how I would implement it.

Comment: I'm just curious, if you care to answer. Why did you explicitly dis-associate your accounts?

Comment: @Robert, I'm not much of a groupthinker and a lot of my "feature-request" questions on meta are unpopular (my average question score is about -2.)  I want prospective employers to see my SO activity but would prefer if they cannot reach my meta account with a single click (if they're really keen they can find it using google.  Not much I can do about that.)  That is not the reason for this request though.

Comment: @Fearless Spammer, so would you provide an "unassociate" button at all?  If so what would it do?

Comment: @Perpetual Motion Goat - I see. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Perptual: It removes the account from your profile. Change your meta display name to further disassociate the accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associated accounts allows the database to "find you" when the question is migrated between sites. When you created the association, meta was able re-address the previous questions to your meta account. As far as the meta database is concerned, your meta account is the author of those questions.

It's like having your mail forwarded. The post was "re-addressed" to your meta account. Just because you disassociated your meta account (i.e. stopped having your mail forwarded), the database doesn't go through and somehow *disassociate* all the old messages.

Comment: I understand that, but would prefer "disassociate" to do the opposite of "associate."  And it doesn't.